# horizontal menu cross the main div block and sub menu not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

How to create submenu in horizontal menu.

1. I have 40 menu items in parent menu.
2. Some parent menu have child menu also.
3. I need next or previous option to show the rest menu.
4. And submenu should also display.

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amith009/th99H/) of what I have tried.

I didn't add sub menu.

HTML

```
<div class="content">           
    <div id="menu">
        <a href="#" class="right">Right</a>
        <a href="#" class="left">Left</a>
        <ul>
            <li>Item Lits 1</li>
            <li>Item Lits 2</li>
            <li>Item Lits 3 </li>
            <li>Item Lits 4</li>
            <li>...</li>
        </ul>  
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.content{
    margin:0px auto;
    width:400px;
    border:1px solid #d7d7d7;
    padding:10px;
    min-height: 400px;
}


#menu {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#menu ul {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#menu ul li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    width: auto;              
    text-align: center;
}

a.left, a.right {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 4px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background: #2a2a2a;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

a.right {
    right: 0;            
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/amith009/th99H/

Comment: You probably want `left: '+=50px'` and `left: '-=50px'` for a start. And I'm not sure what the callbacks are meant to be doing in your example.

Comment: Hi Sam, I was try to move my menu track to show next menu items.

Comment: Could you please explain the question a bit more clearly for me.?

Comment: Hi sunil, I have 100 Items in top menu or some items have sub menu. i want all item come in one line but browser scroll should not come. i have option to use next and previous option. may be your points are clear. if not please refer the fiddle link.